# Age and Interests fields isn't exported to BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

How can I query some of the automatically collected user 
properties from the Firebase database?

I'm looking for attributes that are not available on BigQuery tables named as `app_events`. For instance, I am looking for user attributes 
`age`, `gender`, and `interests` as listed [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Please show us what you've tried so far. It will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: For other people, see thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235202/get-demographic-information-from-bigquery-connected-with-firebase-analytics

Answer (score 0):

The properties you are looking for are available on the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) of your project. Click "Analytics" below the Firebase logo, and then select the appropriate tab, e.g. "Audiences" to see the data you are requesting. As far as I know, they are not accessible from within your application.

Comment: Thanks man, but i would like to export it to bigquery. Is it possible?