# Get demographic information from bigquery connected with firebase analytics

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I export Firebase Analytics data to  BigQuery and I have some problems with demographics queries.

I want to do queries about gender or age but I don't found this information in 
[BigQuery Export schema](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512) or [Event and parameter details](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7061705?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512).

Someone know how I can do this?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

User properties are attributes you define to describe segments of your userbase, such as language preference or geographic location.

Analytics automatically logs some [`user properties`](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486); you don't need to add any code to enable them. If your app needs to collect additional data, you can set up to 25 different Analytics User Properties in your app. See more details [`here`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/properties)

Note: Age, Gender, and Interests properties are automatically collected only if your app links to the Ad Support framework. Linking to this framework also automatically collects the Advertising Identifier (IDFA).

Demographics and interests data in Firebase Analytics:

> Firebase Analytics collects demographics and interests data from the
>   following sources:
>
> - The Android Advertising ID. Applies to app activity only. When you use the Firebase Analytics tracking code in an Android app, Firebase
>     Analytics generates an identifier based on the ID that includes
>     demographic and interest information associated with users’ app
>     activity.
> - The iOS Identifier for Advertisers (IDFA). Applies to app activity only. When you use the Firebase Analytics tracking code in an iOS app
>     to collect the IDFA, Firebase Analytics generates an identifier based
>     on the IDFA that includes demographic and interest information
>     associated with users’ app activity.
>
> When the Device Advertising ID is not present, Firebase Analytics
>   cannot collect demographics and interests information. Consequently,
>   demographics and interests data may only be available for a subset of
>   your users, and may not represent the overall composition of your
>   traffic.

Also, looks like Firebase Analytics demographic reports is thresholded for privacy reasons. Once you have enough data -- at least 10 users per age/gender bracket -- data for that bracket will be shown.

> Update

Age, Gender and Interests are proprietary Google-owned data which are not exported to BigQuery.

Comment: Firebase Analytics is collecting demographics information, I can see it in the  dashboard but I want to create queries about this.

 I also thing that is some about privacy reasons but I am not sure

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Analytics will not export demographics information to BigQuery for user privacy reasons. Mikhail Berlyant answer correctly list the requirements to report on demographics in Firebase Reports but even if you have correct setup and more then 10 users the data will not be exported to bug query. You can select the Firebase Analytics chart in the report and copy/paste it to get csv report on the aggregates. You can not get individual user reports in BigQuery.