# Firebase Audiences not reflecting data in cvs inform

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

We are using firebase in one of our apps and in the Firebase server we can see the demographic data without problems[image], but when we download the informn as a .csv there is no data in the percentage of male in a age from 18-24, 25-34....[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it is working fine as demographic data is not exported from Firebase to BigQuery due to privacy issues, which means the data exported to CSV may also not contain it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235202/get-demographic-information-from-bigquery-connected-with-firebase-analytics/43235715#43235715) question provides some insight on the same issue.